# Firebase push token works only a few times

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with sending push notifications to my react native apps via firebase cloud messaging. I get the push token from the device and store it in my database.

When calling the push notification from the back end (nodejs), it works a few times and I see the push notification on my phone. After about two times of sending the notification, all of a sudden it starts giving me a failure

> List of tokens that caused failures: {"responses":[{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}}],"successCount":0,"failureCount":1}

Then I get another message on the next one, which is the message going forward:

> List of tokens that caused failures: {"responses":[{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/registration-token-not-registered","message":"Requested entity was not found."}}],"successCount":0,"failureCount":1}

This is my code for sending push notifications on nodejs:

```
const message = {

        tokens: registrationTokens,
        notification: {
            "title": "TEST",
            "body": "TEST body"
        },
        data: {
            "action": "New_Card",
            "unique_id": 1
        }
    }
    fbMsging.sendMulticast(message)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.failureCount > 0) {
                const failedTokens = [];
                response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                    if (!resp.success) {
                        failedTokens.push(registrationTokens[idx]);
                    }
                });
                console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + failedTokens);
                callback(false);
            } else {
                console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
                callback(true);
            }
        });
```

Please advise.

Comment: You have two distinct error messages, and they might not be related to each other.  The first error is suggesting that you passed something invalid to the API, but we can't see what that is, since everything is hidden behind variables.  I suggest breaking this down into something more discrete with hard coded values that are easily visible.

Comment: I updated it, with clear values, but yeah I call the same function 2 times and it works then third timessays invalid argument,and fourth time on just says no registered